# PostgreSQL Query Optimization musicbrainz

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, musicbrainz

Hi I have this postgresql code that I want to optimize to use less temporary disk space:

```
SELECT l1.name, l2.name
FROM label l1 INNER JOIN label l2 ON l1.id > l2.id INNER JOIN
label l3 ON l1.id <> l3.id AND l2.id <> l3.id 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM release_label rl1 INNER JOIN release_label rl2 ON rl1.release = rl2.release WHERE rl1.label = l1.id AND rl2.label = l2.id) AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM release_label rl1 INNER JOIN release_label rl3 ON rl1.release = rl3.release WHERE rl1.label = l1.id AND rl3.label = l3.id) AND
EXISTS (SELECT * FROM release_label rl2 INNER JOIN release_label rl3 ON rl2.release = rl3.release WHERE rl2.label = l2.id AND rl3.label = l3.id)`
```

The database that im using is musicbrainz
but it gives me this error:

"could not write block 1973434 of temporary file: No space left on device"

I have a simplified version of the musicbrainz database which has less rows and it works perfectly, please help me find a way to optimize this code, cheers

Comment: If there's really not enough space to execute the query, then you should fix that problem first.  _Maybe_ someone could give you a version which requires less memory, but that is not a direct solution.

Comment: "We are gonna need a bigger **disk**" - Jaws

Comment: i imagined, i thought there might be a way to optimize my query, thanks for the responses

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the execution plan for that query using `EXPLAIN` (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: Even though it may be possible to reduce the memory or disk the query requires, it's like fighting a loosing battle. The query may work today, and crash tomorrow (if, for example, someone uploads a file to the server).

Comment: You should explain what you want the query to do.  How big is `label`?  Cross joining 3 times is rather expensive.  For instance, if it has 1,000 rows, then you are dealing with an intermediate table of approximately 1,000,000,000 rows.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a [recursive query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)?